# QGisPlugin : Trigger closeEvent by clicking 'X' in QgsAttributeForm

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

This is the code:

```
def formOpen(dialog, layer, feature):
   """Function called when a connec is identified in the map"""

   global feature_dialog
   # Create class to manage Feature Form interaction
   feature_dialog = ParentDialog(dialog, layer, feature)
   init_config()

def init_config():
   pass

class ParentDialog():
   def __init__(self, dialog, layer, feature):
   """ Constructor class """

       self.dialog = dialog
       self.layer = layer
       self.feature = feature
       self.iface = iface
```

I want to show message when button X(of `QgsAttributeForm`) is clicked ,something like:

```
    def closeEvent(self, event):
       
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
        "Are you sure to quit?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes,QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

Is there any way to relate dialog (`QgsAttributeForm`) with `closeEvent`, or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

The QgsAttributeForm is part of a QDialog, so you can access the original PyQt5 functions by calling dialog.parent()